# Update one column (with NAs) based on the conditions of another column using R

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

Given a small data set as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2021-09", "2021-10", "2021-11", "2021-12", 
"2021-06", "2021-10"), act_direction = c("decrease", "increase", 
NA, NA, "unchanged", "unchanged"), pred_direction = c(NA, "decrease", 
NA, NA, "decrease", "increase"), direction_acc = c("true", "-", 
"-", "true", "false", "false")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

**df:**

```
     date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
1 2021-09      decrease           <NA>          true
2 2021-10      increase       decrease             -
3 2021-11          <NA>           <NA>             -
4 2021-12          <NA>           <NA>          true
5 2021-06     unchanged       decrease         false
6 2021-10     unchanged       increase         false
```

I try to update `direction_acc` based on `act_direction` column, more specifically, if `act_direction==unchanged`, then I want to update to the content of `direction_acc` to `true`, ignoring whatever its original values are.

The expected result:

```
     date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
1 2021-09      decrease           <NA>          true
2 2021-10      increase       decrease             -
3 2021-11          <NA>           <NA>             -
4 2021-12          <NA>           <NA>          true
5 2021-06     unchanged       decrease          true
6 2021-10     unchanged       increase          true
```

I used code below which I find no error, but it returns an outcome which is out of expectation since other values in `direction_acc` were changed to `NA`s:

```
df %>% 
  # mutate_all(na_if, '') %>% # I will replace empty cell '' to NA as example data
  mutate(direction_acc = ifelse(act_direction == 'unchanged', 
                                'true', 
                                as.character(direction_acc)))
```

Result:

```
     date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
1 2021-09      decrease           <NA>          true
2 2021-10      increase       decrease             -
3 2021-11          <NA>           <NA>          <NA>
4 2021-12          <NA>           <NA>          <NA>
5 2021-06     unchanged       decrease          true
6 2021-10     unchanged       increase          true
```

So my question is why when `act_direction` with `NA`s, `direction_acc` also become `NA`s, and how could we achieve that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### base R

```r
df$direction_acc[df$act_direction == "unchanged"] <- "true"
df
#      date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
# 1 2021-09                                       true
# 2 2021-10                     decrease             -
# 3 2021-11                                          -
# 4 2021-12                                       true
# 5 2021-06     unchanged       decrease          true
# 6 2021-10     unchanged       increase          true
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    direction_acc = if_else(act_direction == "unchanged", "true", direction_acc)
  )
```

If I add the `NA`s as you have (I'll use `across` as `mutate_if` is deprecated), then we can change `==` to `%in%` for the desired effect.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.character), ~ na_if(., ""))) %>%
  mutate(
    direction_acc = if_else(act_direction %in% "unchanged", "true", direction_acc)
  )
#      date act_direction pred_direction direction_acc
# 1 2021-09          <NA>           <NA>          true
# 2 2021-10          <NA>       decrease             -
# 3 2021-11          <NA>           <NA>             -
# 4 2021-12          <NA>           <NA>          true
# 5 2021-06     unchanged       decrease          true
# 6 2021-10     unchanged       increase          true
```

Comment: Sorry, code with `dplyr` seems not working, I'll slightly edit data to help u test it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have two questions: 1. do u know why we can't use `act_direction == "unchanged" ` for `mutate()` when there are NAs inside; 2. `transform(direction_acc = if_else(act_direction %in% "unchanged", "true", direction_acc))` is equivalent to `mutate(direction_acc = if_else(act_direction %in% "unchanged", "true", direction_acc))`, right?

Comment: (1) `NA == "unchanged"` returns `NA`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`, so there are logical issues with relying on it. `NA %in% "unchanged"`, however, returns `FALSE` (as we expect and need it to). When there is an `NA` in the logical, that will carry over into the value returned from `if_else`, c.f., `if_else(c(T,NA,F), 1:3, 11:13)` returns `c(1,NA,13)`. (2) For the most part, yes. Two of the bigger differences: `transform` variables created cannot use new variables created previously within the same `transform`, while in `mutate` that works. And `across` is mutate-only.

Comment: Cool, thanks again for sharing your code and insights.